# Search result page with tabs and ajax pagination

Tags: 8, ajax, search

I need to create a results search page with those characteristics:

- The page will have different tabs (like the bootstrap ones so no page reload), each tab will only shows the relative content type. There needs to be a “all” tab with all the content as well
- Each tab needs to have a “load more” button on the bottom for ajax pagination

I can alter the search-results template and having the tabs, but I don’t know how to integrate an ajax pagination on each singular tab by using drupal functions (or using Views Infinite Scroll if it will be a view)

Any hints?